Amplify Gen 2: Filter by Case-Insensitive String
I'm trying to do the equivalent of a basic SQL LIKE filter on a list, and it seems the closest option using GraphQL is to use contains, which is case-sensitive. Is there a way to do a case-insensitive comparison using contains, or am I barking up the wrong tree entirely?

As far as I know in the current state of Gen 2 amplify you can only do case insensitive query filters with Open Search added to your project. In Gen 1 they had the @searchable directive which is no longer available in Gen 2. Instead you have to manually add Open Search to your project by following these steps in their documentation:
Adding Open Search in Gen 2
